# TypeError - 'int' object is not callable in Lambda Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I'm trying to find duplicates and group them in "technician" table.

```
display(technician['Tech_id'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).head())
duplicate_technicians = technician.groupby('Tech_id').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 2)
```

This line throws an error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Error is particularly in the lambda function.

```
duplicate_technicians.filter(lambda x: len(x) == 2)
```

Here is the "technician" table for reference,

[image]

I'm new to this. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you created a variable somewhere in your code which you have called len and sotred in an int in it. `len=40` this will overwrite the built in function of len. Now when you do `len(x)` it would be like doing `40(x)` and like the code says an int is not callable like that

Comment: I've updated the code. Please check it.

Comment: To check what @ChrisDoyle pointed out, simply check `print(len)`. Please, verify that it's output is `<built-in function len>`

Comment: I'm getting the output as 3.

Comment: So like i said, you have assigned an int to the name `len` somewhere in your code causing you to have overwritten the built in function of len. dont call variables names that are of built in functions of python. when i do `print(len)` my output is `<built-in function len>`